# pulseaudio: bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply:

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I'm getting an error when starting pulseaudio. How do I fix this?

Immediately after startup I do:

```
$sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/*
```

Nothing is returned. Then:

```
$ pulseaudio
E: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
^Z
$ sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/*
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  joeuser   3178 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/controlC1:  joeuser   3178 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/pcmC0D7p:   joeuser   3178 F...m pulseaudio
/dev/snd/pcmC1D0c:   joeuser   3178 F...m pulseaudio
/dev/snd/pcmC1D0p:   joeuser   3178 F...m pulseaudio
```

So now pulseaudio appears to be runnning though no sound devices appear on settings:

[image: Settings-Sound]

Comment: Read the thread below, hope it helps
[(pulseaudio) bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024012/pulseaudio-bluez5-util-c-getmanagedobjects-failed-org-freedesktop-dbus-err)